# AngularJS Routing All Within One HTML page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am working with a serverless HTML so JavaScript cannot load other html content. I was wondering if there is an example of pulling the template from the DOM so that I can pack all my views into a single HTML file (i.e. without having to use string templates).

Would this work?

I am working with AngularJS 1.7.5 rather than the newer Angular 2.

I need it to work with Outlook/IE.

I was thinking of just getting the .InnerHTML of some base element. Advice, notes, concerns?

Comment: You can use `<script type="text/ng-template" id="/myTemplate.html"></script>` to inline your templates. [Check out the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script) for more information.

Comment: That is far better than my idea.